# Facebook notifications from page (application) tab

Tags: facebook

I am developing sort of Q&A app in facebook where users ask question and admin answers them.  I would like  to be able to send a notification (facebook globe thing) to user when admin answers the question.  I found that i could be done with [request dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) but i cant find anywhere if the dialog can be sent on behalf of the page not the admin himself.

So my question can it be done so that i dont have to display admins name?  Maybe there is a better way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests dialog is meant for inviting users to use the app, it's not meant to send other notifications, since the dialog is for "user to user" notifications, and what you're describing is "app to user" notification.

The app requests won't appear in the globe icon, but instead the user will see a counter (showing the number of notifications) next to the app name in the bookmarked apps section.

You can read more about this issue in the [Requests documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) and also in the [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/).